# Virtual memory - Page on RAM and in hard drive at the same time?

Tags: paging, virtual-memory, page-fault

Can a page be, at the same time, in physical memory and in virtual memory?

If I ask for an address that's on virtual memory, will it always trigger a page fault? If the first question is true, then it should only trigger a page fault if the page is not also in physical memory. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a page be at the same time in physical memory and in virtual
>   memory?

When you page out a memory block you need the space for other stuff, so it would make no sense to have it in RAM and in page file.

> If I ask for an address that's on virtual memory, will it always
>   trigger a page fault? If the first question is true, then it should
>   only trigger a page fault if the page is not also in physical memory.
>   Is that right?

Yes thats right. Pagefaults cause an interrupt. If you always had a pagefault when you access memory than you had only very little performace.